# Select linked objects from Query in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a database where I store mouse IDs and FMRI measurement sessions, the classes (with greatly reduced columns, for convenience) look as follows:

```
class FMRIMeasurement(Base):
    __tablename__ = "fmri_measurements"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(DateTime)
    animal_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('animals.id'))

class Animal(Base):
    __tablename__ = "animals"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id_eth = Column(Integer)
    fmri_measurements = relationship("FMRIMeasurement", backref="animal")
```

I would like to create a pandas dataframe cntaining all of the details of all of the FMRIMeasurements assigned to one particular animal. Selecting data from that animal works fine:

```
mystring = str(session.query(Animal).filter(Animal.id_eth == 1))
print pd.read_sql_query(mystring, engine, params=[4001])
```

But as soon as I try to select the FMRIMeasurements it blows up. None of the follwing work.

```
mystring = str(session.query(Animal.fmri_measurements).filter(Animal.id_eth == 1))

mystring = str(session.query(FMRIMeasurement).filter(FMRIMeasurement.animal.id_eth == 1))

mystring = str(session.query(Animal.fmri_measurements.date).filter(Animal.id_eth == 1))
```

I guess I'm just using SQLAlchemy wrong, but I couldn't find anything to help me with my use case in the docs (perhaps I don't know how wthat I want to do is actually called) :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session.query` makes a query string, you need to actually execute it using `.first()` or `.all()` to get the resultset

For instance

```
sql_query = session.query(Animal.fmri_measurements).filter(Animal.id_eth == 1)

result_set = sql_query.all() # execute the query and return resultset

for item in result_set:
    # do work with item

    # if the item changes and you want to commit the changes
    session.merge(item)

# commit changes
session.commit()
```

Alterantively you do not need the .all() and iterating through a query object will execute it as well

```
sql_query = session.query(Animal.fmri_measurements).filter(Animal.id_eth == 1)
for item in sql_query:
    #do something
```

To then get the pandas dataframe, you can run:

```
mystring = str(session.query(Weight))
print pd.read_sql_query(mystring,engine)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I actually have a follow-up question, but I decided it's big enough to be better suited on a separate page than here in the comments. Can you maybe help me out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35208961/filter-query-by-linked-object-key-in-sqlalchemy Basically this solution works if the columns contain Stings, Floats, Ints, but it does not work if I want to filter by related objects.