# Filter query by linked object key in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas, sqlalchemy

Judging by the title [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010454/sqlalchemy-filter-query-by-related-object) would be the exact same question, but I can't see how any of the answers are applicable to my use case:

I have two classes and a relationship between them:

```
treatment_association = Table('tr_association', Base.metadata,
    Column('chronic_treatments_id', Integer, ForeignKey('chronic_treatments.code')),
    Column('animals_id', Integer, ForeignKey('animals.id'))
)

class ChronicTreatment(Base):
    __tablename__ = "chronic_treatments"
    code = Column(String, primary_key=True)

class Animal(Base):
    __tablename__ = "animals"
    treatment = relationship("ChronicTreatment", secondary=treatment_association, backref="animals")
```

I would like to be able to select only the animals which have undergon a treatment which has the code "X". I tried quite a few approaches.

This one fails with an `AttributeError`:

```
sql_query = session.query(Animal.treatment).filter(Animal.treatment.code == "chrFlu")
for item in sql_query:
    pass

mystring = str(session.query(Animal))
```

And this one happily returns a list of unfiltered animals:

```
sql_query = session.query(Animal.treatment).filter(ChronicTreatment.code == "chrFlu")
for item in sql_query:
    pass

mystring = str(session.query(Animal))
```

The closest thing to the example from the aforementioned thread I could put together:

```
subq = session.query(Animal.id).subquery()
sql_query = session.query(ChronicTreatment).join((subq, subq.c.treatment_id=="chrFlu"))
for item in sql_query:
    pass

mystring = str(session.query(Animal))
mydf = pd.read_sql_query(mystring,engine)
```

Also fails with an `AttributeError`.

Can you hel me sort this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there are two issues with table definitions:

1) In the `treatment_association` you have `Integer` column pointing to `chronic_treatments.code` while the `code` is `String` column.

I think it's just better to have an integer `id` in the `chronic_treatments`, so you don't duplicate the string code in another table and also have a chance to add more fields to chronic_treatments later.
Update: not exactly correct, you still can add more fields, but it will be more complex to change your 'code' if you decide to rename it.

2) In the `Animal` model you have a relation named `treatment`. This is confusing because you have many-to-many relation, it should be plural - `treatments`.

After fixing the above two, it should be clearer why your queries did not work.
This one (I replaced `treatment` with `treatments`:

```
sql_query = session.query(Animal.treatments).filter(
    Animal.treatments.code == "chrFlu")
```

The `Animal.treatments` represents a many-to-many relation, it is not an SQL Alchemy mode, so you can't pass it to the `query` nor use in a `filter`.

Next one can't work for the same reason (you pass `Animal.treatments` into the `query`.

The last one is closer, you actually need `join` to get your results.

I think it is easier to understand the query as SQL (and you anyway need to know SQL to be able to use sqlalchemy):

```
animals = session.query(Animal).from_statement(text(
    """
       select distinct animals.* from animals
       left join tr_association assoc on assoc.animals_id = animals.id
       left join chronic_treatments on chronic_treatments.id = assoc.chronic_treatments_id
       where chronic_treatments.code = :code
 """)
).params(code='chrFlu')
```

It will select `animals` and join `chronic_treatments` through the `tr_association` and filter the result by code.

Having this it is easy to rewrite it using SQL-less syntax:

```
sql_query = session.query(Animal).join(Animal.treatments).filter(
    ChronicTreatment.code == "chrFlu")
```

That will return what you want - a list of animals who have related chronic treatment with given code.

Comment: Great response, thank you! but why would a string `code` give me the chance to add more fields to chronic_treatments later? Also, the `code` is set as my primary key, so why would I be risking uplicating it? would I not get a warning?

Comment: @TheChymera you are right, you still can add more fields, my bad ))) But it is still not good to have it as a primary key because you duplicate it at least in two tables (strings usually take more space and it will be harder to change the code if you want too). So it is better to have an `id` and `code`, for `code` you can add an `unique` constraint.

Comment: I tried your modifications and [this](https://bpaste.net/show/635516c61783) returns an empty dataframe, while [this](https://bpaste.net/show/721ec14b4c70) returns a list with all my animals. Any ideas why I can't implement your solution?

Comment: @TheChymera the session.query(...) doesn't return the data directly, you need to loop over it to get the results or you can use `sql_query.all()` to actually fetch all data. See my full test code [here](https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/blob/master/sql-alchemy/test_filter_by_joined_table.py).

Comment: @TheChymera [here](https://bpaste.net/show/635516c61783) you don't fetch data from the `sql_query`, you need `sql_query.all()`. And [here](https://bpaste.net/show/721ec14b4c70) you don't use the `sql_query` result, instead you do one more `session.query(Animal)`, but if it works then probably your first example should work too, maybe there are actually no animals with 'chrFlu'? Anyway, check my [test example](https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/blob/master/sql-alchemy/test_filter_by_joined_table.py), it actually works.